# Managing Telerik .NET references in a Git environment

Tags: c#, .net, git, telerik

We've got about two dozen projects, which all use different NuGet-packages and a bunch of Telerik WPF libraries, the latter are usually added by GAC, which on its own does not add a hint path to the csproj-File. (Good)

As soon as we use Telerik's upgrade wizard to simultaneously upgrade the references of all projects, Telerik starts copying the files to a local lib folder next to the bin folder and adds hintpaths, which do not exist on other developers machines AND need to be discarded before pushing to Git every time. (Bad)

BTW: We regularly get the same problem (regarding hintpath) with the Spire NuGet-Package.

Now we came up with some suggestions, which we internally valued differently and therefore did not come to an accord:

- Keep discarding the chunks containing the hint path
- Ask Telerik to fix the wizard
- Check the libraries into Git
- Add Telerik libraries using their NuGet server
- Create a Libaries-Path we manage by hand, maybe as a network drive

What's other peoples approach to handling those issues?

Comment: So what's a problem exactly with just checking those libraries into git? Then your state is always consistent and no need to perform external actions (such as running upgrade wizard on every machine).

Comment: @Evk, what's the problem with using NuGet? What's the problem with using a library folder? No problem, just want input on how it's done correctly / preferably. Idealy from a credible source. But counterquestion: why don't have all open source projects their neccessary third party libraries incorporated even if those are open source libraries under the same license?

Comment: NuGet is preferrable if possible, almost everyone agrees on that, though there is downside - your codebase now has an external dependency and if one day given nuget package will become unavailable for some reason - you have a problem. Both nuget and adding libs directly to git provide consistency and convenience - you just pull, build and done, even from the fresh machine. As for your question - if we are talking about .NET libraries - almost everyone uses nuget nowadays, so their dependencies are usually available there. And if not (rare) - they do include them directly in git.

Comment: You can easily cache the packages in a shared folder. Then if NuGet goes down, you can still continue to work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for "Check the libraries into git".

Rationale: when a developer (or CI system) checks out your project from source control, he should be able to build it right away without having to install dependencies like GAC assemblies.

Comment: Thank you for you input. Care to elaborate on the fact why most repositories might not include libraries? Even those who just reference open source projects and could easily integrate them without licensing problems? Do you know of any public repositories or professional developers who do incorporate the third party libraries? Bounty is open. Thanks

Comment: You can achieve the same desired effect (not having to install anything into the GAC) by using the NuGet packages. It's a much cleaner solution and the de-facto standard nowadays.

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski problem might be, that Telerik manages each of it's libraries in a seperate NuGet package and we use around 5 to 20 in each project, so that's over a hundred packages to update every iteration. Opposed to using Telerik's wizard which updates all lib-Folders.

Comment: @SlapY yeah, I don't use Telerik but I understand the issue... I actually have developed a standalone package updater because of this. We have *a ton* of projects that use *a lot* of packages and some of those need to be kept in sync. Definitely not something you can do from VS. But having many NuGet packages in a single project is something that has become standard practice now: just try to add a reference to the Roslyn compiler for an example and you'll see what I mean ;)

Comment: @SlapY as stated above, a package manager like NuGet helps in not including the libraries; but still achieves the same result of allowing anyone to build without manual install. However you clearly hit a problem with NuGet that would be solved by checking in the libraries.

Comment: Due to the fact that there is no "Update All" feature for NuGet packages, this is ultimatively the correct answer to deal with Telerik's two dozen libraries (Use the wizard to upgrade, check in the lib folder). However, since I agree with most of the others, @Jaffal get's the Bounty

Comment: That's fair, @SlapY :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use NuGet for that, it's the easiest and most organized way, you should not have a problem for other developers when you install a new package as long as you are committing package.config file, in this case any one will do a build of the solution visual studio will automatically restore NuGet Package.

Make sure to set your NuGet settings as below image shows:

[image]

Comment: I'm going to reward you with the bounty, since I think this is would be the correct answer.. if it wasn't for Telerik and NuGet's missing "Update All" function. However, Amaud Well gets the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Telerik wizard. Add the Telerik dependencies using NuGet. They have a private NuGet repository. See the tutorial [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/nuget-install).

Comment: Thank you, I've added this suggestion to the possibilities!